# How to pass a string object with apostrophe to POST call

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Implementing [add watcher to JIRA issue api](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/issue-addWatcher).
It takes a string object as data input.

When making a post call using python requests, I'm doing this:

`data = "\"" + data + "\""
req = requests.post(full_url, headers=headers, data=data)`

Is there a better way to pass a string parameter to the post call while persisting the apostrophe?

Comment: also JIRA has an API for python you might want to check out

Comment: You could use single - quotes

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner way will be via using [`str.format(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) function as:

```
# string within single quote 
data = '"{}"'.format(data)

# OR, string as double quote but with escape character as
data = "\"{}\"".format(data)
```